# Get difference between two files using svn+python

Tags: python, svn

I would like to figure out how to do the following

`svn diff –r REVNO:HEAD FilePath`

Using the `svn` python wrapper. I have tried the following:

```
import svn.local
l = svn.local.LocalClient(FilePath)
ModifiedFiles = l.diff_summary(6382,6383) #List of dicts containing modified files and some attributes
Difference = l.diff(6382, 6383, FilePath) #throws error
```

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/TEMP/SVN/comparison/GetLines.py", line 6, in 
>       Difference = l.diff(6382, 6383)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\svn\common.py", line 447, in diff
>       for non_empty_diff in filter(None, diff_result.decode('utf8').split('Index: ')): UnicodeDecodeError:
>   'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 396852: invalid
>   continuation byte

In the subversion command line it works fine though.

How can I use the python wrapper to get the changes for a particular file?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in `pysvn`. The function `diff` silently assumes a `utf8`-encoding of the files, but if a file has a different encoding (e.g. `ISO 8859-1`, also called `Latin-1`) then characters with ASCII code > 127 = `0x7f` (e.g. `0xda` = 'Ö' in `Latin-1`) are interpreted wrongly as a multi-byte character and in many cases this will lead to a non-existing byte combination, hence the decode error.

I have encountered this error myself and [filed a bug](https://github.com/dsoprea/PySvn/issues/114) just now.